# How to handle right to left languages in Flash (pre version 10)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, arabic

We are currently working with Flex creating a web application. We are having trouble taking Arabic text from the user and displaying correctly (like in a chat feature). While presumably Flash 10 will solve this problem, we don't want to force our users to upgrade.

Flash flips the order of the sentence's words. so if I wrote something like "Hello World" in the text field, it will appear as "World Hello" in the chat area.

Is there a standard way to work with Right to Left languages in Flash?

*We currently flip the order of the words with a function, but it things get messed up when using English or special characters in the chat like :) or :D *

Comment: I've had nothing but trouble in dynamic RTL text for flash - and I know I'm not the only one. It was impossible, for all intents and purposes, last time I checked, and v10 is supposed to improve the situation, but short of making requests to an exteral app which renders the text as a .png...

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check FlarabyAS3Flex [here](http://www.arabicode.com/en/flaraby/as3/flex/)

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be a Unicode issue, and so a quick talaash via Google gave me [Unicode in Flash](http://polygeek.com/110_flex_unicode-in-flash), but probably more to the point is [Flash: RTL (right-to-left)](http://www.blog.lessrain.com/flash-ltr-left-to-right-and-rtl-right-to-left/), seeing as it mentions Arabic (along with other RTL languages) as well as [RTL text output class for Flash](http://www.electroinn.com/blog/?p=6).

HTH

Comment: How can I have RTL without AS3 !?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try this:
http://www.red-id.com/blog/category/RTL-Flash.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no decent way to support that. Anything you try will be a hack and will break for some cases. And definitely not work for editing.

I would say: ask the users to update.

The penetration of Player 10 is already above 90% in all markets (http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html).

And users can understand that you have no choice. It is "update or support for your language is abysmal".

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://giladmanor.blogspot.com/2009/03/flex-right-to-left-for-hebrew-man.html) is an example for handling the text direction in flex.