# Arabic font displays in reverse order... i need to load xml file in Flash

Tags: xml, flash, fonts, adobe

Ive got text in arabic in Word doc, written right to left (its times new roman font, arabic characters). when I copy & paste in XML, it reverses the direction, becomes left to right.

Im using word 2003 & adobe CS3 
i need to load xml file in Flash .

Comment: Type directly into the xml???

Comment: No . i am coping Arabic sentences into XML. so is it coping in reverse form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Notepad++ http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ to save your xml file it has an Text Direction option on the View menu, set this to RTL or use CTRL + ALT + R.

If the problem is with in flash, Flash 10 supports RTL languages (see http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/), for versions prior to this see [How to handle right to left languages in Flash (pre version 10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292316/how-to-handle-right-to-left-languages-in-flash-pre-version-10), it is possible but not straight forward. I think I resorted to including one displayable line per xml field last time I had to do this.